# Under what circumstances is bidirectional bubble sort better than standard bubble sort?

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort

I have implemented the bidirectional bubble sort algorithm. But I can't think of a scenario where bidirectional bubble sort better than standard bubble sort..can some one give me some clue?

My implementation in Python:

```
def bubbleSort_v(my_list):
    s = 0
    e = 0
    right = True
    for index in range(len(my_list)-1,0,-1):
        if right:
            right = False
            for idx in range(s,index+e,1):
                if my_list[idx] > my_list[idx+1]:
                    my_list[idx],my_list[idx+1] = my_list[idx+1],my_list[idx]
            s += 1
        else:
            right = True
            for idx in range(index-1+s,e,-1):
                if my_list[idx] < my_list[idx-1]:
                    my_list[idx],my_list[idx-1] = my_list[idx-1],my_list[idx]
            e += 1
    return my_list
```

Thanks!

Comment: both terrible in all situations

Comment: Both the intro and the "Differences from Bubble Sort" on Wikipedia discuss your question with examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort

Comment: Friends don't let friends use bubble sort. The only reason to study the bubble sort family is because they're simple to understand, and it's generally easy to explain why virtually any other sorting algorithm is superior (of course, excluding crazy things like bogosort).

Comment: @GarrGodfrey not *all*. If your data is already sorted or nearly sorted, bubble sort can be acceptable. Maybe still not the best choice, but at least not *terrible*.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Careful. There are meticuluously contrived theoretical situations where Bubble Sort is optimal and your favorite sorting algorithms are dreadful.

Comment: What Mark Ransom said. OTOH, Python's fabulous TimSort is also very good at sorting data that contains sequences that are already sorted. So if you have a sorted list and append (or insert) random stuff to it & re-sort, TimSort will handle the job efficiently. Similarly, it will efficiently merge data from a bunch of sorted lists that have been concatenated together.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is an element that is at the right (for instance the last index) of the list, that should be moved to the left side (for instance the first index) of the list. This will take a long time with single-directional bubble-sort: each time it will move only one step.

If we perform bi-directional bubblesort however, the element will be moved to the left in the first step to the right.

So in general it is better if **one or more elements should be moved** (over a large number of places) in the **opposite direction in which the single direction bubblesort is done.**

For your implementation of bubblesort, it will however not make much difference: usually bubblesort will test while it sorts. In case it can do a full run without swaps, it will simply stop working.

For example a single-directional bubblesort that moves to the *right*:

```
def single_bubble(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        can_exit = True
        for j in range(len(data)-i-1):
            if data[j] > data[j+1]:
                data[j],data[j+1] = data[j+1],data[j]
                can_exit = False
        if can_exit:
            return
```

So in case you want to move an element a large number of places to the *left*, then for each such step, you will have to do a full loop again. We can optimize the above method a bit more, but this behavior cannot be eliminated.

Bi-directional bubblesort can be implemented like:

```
def single_bubble(data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        can_exit = True
        for j in range(len(data)-i-1):
            if data[j] > data[j+1]:
                data[j],data[j+1] = data[j+1],data[j]
                can_exit = False
        if can_exit:
            return
        for j in range(len(data)-i,i,-1):
            if data[j-i] > data[j]:
                data[j-1],data[j] = data[j],data[j-1]
                can_exit = False
        if can_exit:
            return
```

That being said, **bubble sort is *not* a good sorting algorithm in general**. There exist way better algorithms like *quicksort*, *mergesort*, *timsort*, *radixsort* (for numerical data), etc.

Bubblesort is actually a quite bad algorithm even among *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithms, since it will move an object one place at a time. Insertion sort will simply first calculate what has to move and then move that part of the list quite fast saving a lot of useless moves. The algorithms can however serve an educational purpose when learning to design, implement and analyze algorithms, since the algorithms will perform significantly bad compared to more advanced ones.

Implementing (general purpose) sorting function yourself is probably not beneficial: good algorithms have been implemented for all popular programming languages and these algorithms are fast, consume less memory, etc.

Comment: Well, for big lists an O(n log n) sort like quicksort or mergesort is going to be superior, but for smaller lists, an O(n^2) may be faster, which is why we have hybrid algorithms that use a O(n^2) for small (sub)lists. But even among the O(n^2) sorts, bubblesort is a worse choice than (for example) eg, selection sort or insertion sort.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, but for small lists, performance is usually not an issue. I think regardless of the algorithm, sorting a list with 10 elements will not significantly contribute to the performance of a program. Usually in that case the bottleneck is somewhere else. Time complexity only is about large amounts of data.

Comment: Sure, and in Python you should almost always use TimSort, unless you know that something like radixsort is appropriate for your data. OTOH, although all modern languages provide sorting facilities it's still a Good Idea for compsci students to learn about the various standard sorting algorithms, not because they'll ever need to implement them in the real world, but because they're a good subject matter to learn about algorithm analysis.